# Ubuntu CD Installation Stuck on Purple Loading Screen

Tags: installation

I burnt Ubuntu 12.04 to a CD since that was the max it could hold. I've used the disc four times before, therefore it's not invalid.

Comment: What type of hardware are you trying to install on?  How long is it stuck before you've given up on it?

Answer (score 0):

the disk might not be invalid , but depending on the state of the disk and or the state of the drive , it might not load properly which is a real pain when it comes to live cds. Try booting from another medium it should atleast boot to a desktop